# What does AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID do?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, ipad

What does `AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID` do?

All I was able to find was this from Apple's site:

```
// Create a system sound object representing the sound file
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID (
        soundFileURLRef,
        &soundFileObject
    );
```

And It isn't very helpful.  I always see it created but then never used.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's used for playing short sounds and alerts. See this [Audio & Video Coding How-To](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/codinghowtos/AudioAndVideo/#PLAYBACK-PLAY_SHORT_SOUNDS_AND_ALERTS) for a very small snippet of sample code.

The [SysSound sample project](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/SysSound/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008018) has slightly more code.

However, the best sample code for using this I've seen is in the [iPhone SDK Development book](http://pragprog.com/titles/amiphd/iphone-sdk-development), chapter 17.2. You can download the code from the book [here](http://pragprog.com/titles/amiphd/source_code). Look for the SystemSoundsDemo project.

Comment: The howto link is now broken. I'm not sure what to replace it with or I'd edit the answer. This is relevant, however slightly different in name: 
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/audiovideo/conceptual/multimediapg/multimediaprogrammingguide.pdf